# Can i use @Value annotation to get system property in ServletContextListener

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a ServletContextListener in my web application. The following works...

```
public class AppServletContextListener 
               implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener {

      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

            String repManInitScript = System.getProperty("REP_MAN_INIT_SCRIPT");
            System.err.println(repManInitScript ); 
       }
}
```

But usign the @Value annotation doesn't....

```
public class AppServletContextListener 
               implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener {

@Value("${REP_MAN_INIT_SCRIPT}")
private String repManInitScript; 

      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

            repManInitScript = System.getProperty("REP_MAN_INIT_SCRIPT");
            System.err.println(repManInitScript ); 
      }
}
```

Is there a way to grab the system property using the @Value annotation?

Thanks

Comment: No you cannot because ServletContextListener is created by the server, not by Spring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can but you have to grab it from the system properties like this:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['REP_MAN_INIT_SCRIPT']}")
private String repManInitScript;
```

I assume you already have this property in your system properties.

And of course `@Value` annotation only works in spring beans. If you try to use it directly in `ServletContextListener` it won't work.

This `${REP_MAN_INIT_SCRIPT}` isn't working because spring looks for the property in your configured properties if you have any of course.

So if you want this to work on initialization you can implement [InitializingBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) in your spring bean and override `afterPropertiesSet` method. Then the value will be available.